# How to initialize the enum Field in a Table?

Tags: enums, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I have two Table, TableA , TableB.
In TableA I have FieldA (EnumType-Noyes) , and the same I have in TableB.

I wanto to initialize with initValue method the value for the fieldA, but I have an error.

I used this code:

```
public void initValue()
{
 TableB tableb;
 this.fieldA = tableb.fieldb; //but can't assing
}
```

In my TableB , the field value (Enum NoYes) is Yes , but in debug i "read" the value NO.

I have to use a find methot for the return this parameter?
Can help me?

Thanks,

enjoy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only declared `TableB` in the `initValue()` method and have not initialized it with any record.

This is basically the difference between:
`Class1 class1` and `Class1 class1 = new Class1()`.

So you need to do:

```
TableB tableb = TableB::find('SearchArgument');
if (tableb)
    this.fieldA = tableb.fieldb;
```

Comment: Alex , here: TableB tableb = TableB::find('SearchArgument');
gave me an error

Comment: Thanks Alex, your advice brought me on the right way!

Answer (score 0):

You need initialization instance of TableB:

```
TableB b = TabelB::find('..');

if(b)
   this.fieldA = b.fieldB
```

You must have method 'find' in TableB.